# How do you change the color of the words in a Python Tkinter OptionMenu

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I am trying to make a Drop Down Menu of colors. Red Green Blue Yellow. I want the words inside the option box to be colored with their respected name. So the when the user clicks the arrow to open the optionMenu, Option red will have red letters. blue will have blue letters and so forth.

Is this Possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Or if there is a way to do that using a different tkinter object

Answer (score 1):

So you just have to use `OptionMenu.entryconfig(*index of item*, background = *color)`

```
m.entryconfig(0, background="GREEN")
m.entryconfig(1, background = "RED")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `fg`(or `foreground`) and `bg`(or `background`) options. If `a` is the menu, use:
`a.entryconfig(` *`optionindex`* `,` `bg="` *`color_name`* `"` `)` for the background, and
`a.entryconfig(` *`optionindex`* `,` `bg=` `"` *`color_name`* `"` `)` for the foreground.