# Is there a way to change the color of a specific option in ttk.OptionMenu on Windows?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu, ttkwidgets

I'm trying to write a code to change the color of a specific option in `ttk.OptionMenu` with press of a button (only that option should appear with the color when seen in the drop down). Here is a code similar to my need.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import OptionMenu

root = Tk()

def ch_color():
    global ent, options
    option = ent.get()
    if option in options:
        #The code to change the color of that option in opt_menu

options = ['option 1','option 2', 'option 3', 'option 4']

var = StringVar()
var.set("Select")
opt_menu = OptionMenu(root, var, *options).pack()

ent = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable = ent).pack()
button = Button(root, text = "Change Color", command = ch_color).pack()
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178153/how-to-change-menu-background-color-of-tkinters-optionmenu-widget), but apparently it changes the color of the entire widget, and not a specific option, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31105836/), but this doesn't work on Windows. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change menu background color of Tkinter's OptionMenu widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178153/how-to-change-menu-background-color-of-tkinters-optionmenu-widget)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I've figured it out already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OptionMenu is a button that shows a menu. The menu is a Tk menu so you can use menu commands on it once you fetch a reference from the OptionMenu widget. eg:

```
menu = opt_menu.nametowidget(opt_menu.cget('menu'))
index = menu.index('option 2')
menu.entryconfigure(index, background='red')
```

This will find the menu index of the 'option 2' entry and change its background color.

Personally I recommend using the ttk.Combobox instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, works perfectly. Also, thank you for the suggestion to use `ttk.Combobox`